# angular validation as service

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'd like to know if there's other options for form validation other than using directives.

Mixing your validation (business) with the view is not what I call separation-of-concerns and it seems validation support is too primitive in angular world.

I'm used to working with knockout and want something like [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation). Validation rules there are set in the view-model, complete and clean separate from the view. Is there any comparable lib to that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ng-change events and then call your validator service.

You can set fields invalid using the `$scope.formName.inputName.$setValidity` method, pass the form to your validation service and you're good to go.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Is there a way to bind $scope.formName model with the controller model ?

Comment: You don't need to bind it, if you name your form and form controls they're automagically available on the $scope object in your controller. I'll try and find a plunkr example for you.

Comment: It's a very simple example but you can see the controller outputting the valid state of a control to the console on save. http://plnkr.co/edit/FmPZwk98DoCOuVn1GmkU?p=preview